# how to Access url After rewrite

Tags: php, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-routing

I am newbee to rewriting rules. i used this site to make rewrite rules.<`http://www.generateit.net/mod-rewrite/index.php`>.

My url is

```
http://example.com/listing-detail.php?id=5
```

And i coverted it to

```
http://photoshoothub.com/5
```

Bu using

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /listing-detail.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But now my question is on my index file i want to give link so i can access `listing-detail.php` file with id `5`

SO which link should i have to give in 
`<a href="????" >` if i give `listing-detail?id=<?=$id?>` So it will shows `http://example.com/listing-detail.php?id=5`.

Any docs or help is appreciated,

Comment: you can directly use converted url directly http://photoshoothub.com/5

Comment: you can still use $_GET by getting an id. Like $_GET['id'].

Comment: @sunilwananje i tried it returns `Object not found!`